# Connection closed by ***** port 22 while using bash.ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to access the server through the ssh command, but if I wait for too long until I enter the password, it shows me that the connection is closed "Connection closed by ***** port 22"(If I don't wait for too long, everything works fine).

Is there any possible way to cover the ssh command with catch/(try again) if password was entered e.g. 1 min later?

I searched through the forums and haven't found any commands for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possible way to cover the ssh command with catch/(try again) if password was entered e.g. 1 min later?

Not really.  Commands run by the shell provide information back to it via their exit status and possibly via their standard streams.  You are running `ssh` in a mode that requires user interaction, so its standard streams are devoted to supporting that interaction. That leaves exit status as all you have to work with.

But according to [its docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html), `ssh`

> exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if
> an error occurred.

That means that although the host shell can detect when something went wrong, it cannot distinguish between errors in which the remote command never executed at all (because the password prompt timed out, for example) and errors reported by the remote command by exiting with status 255.  It also cannot distinguish between different local errors, some of which would not warrant a retry attempt.